# Understanding colliders

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I understand how to add a collider to  a single mesh in blender, but... I want to know if it is possible to enlarge said collider. For instance, I have a model of a briefcase but I want the collider to be a bit larger. How do I do that?

[image]

In addition, is it possible for me to create a single bounding box and keep a bunch of objects inside? For instance if I have the model of a nightstand could I put a collider around it and also put the lamp, cell phone and any other component within that bounding box?

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is simple to create an invisible box, parent your objects to it, and then remove your objects from the physics simulation. The box will then do the collisions on their behalf.

Steps:

1. Remove you meshes from the phsical simulation

[image]

2. Parent your mesh to you box
3. Make your box invisible, and set the simulation to *Rigid Body*

[image]